# HBase record lost upon closing

Tags: hbase

HI, I install Hbase 0.89 (oct release) using local filesystem, for dev and test purpose. I created few tables and rows using hbase shell. somehow whenever i restart hbase, no data/table available. any advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the default local file system stores files in /tmp.  This may be cleaned up by your OS on reboot.  If you must use a local file system, set the location to be something other than /tmp.  Look in the hbase-default.xml config file in ${HBASE_HOME}/conf to see the correct property to set